# Losing type information in powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I have two functions that work together in powershell:

```
Function Get-PropertyValue($fileName, $property)
{
    $path = (Get-Item $fileName).FullName
    $shell = New-Object -COMObject Shell.Application
    $folder = Split-Path $path
    $file = Split-Path $path -Leaf
    $shellfolder = $shell.Namespace($folder)
    $shellfile = $shellfolder.ParseName($file)
    $shellfolder.GetDetailsOf($shellfile,$property)
}
Function Create-List($files, $property)
{
    $list = @{}
    foreach ($file in $files)
    {
        $list.Add($file.toString(),(Get-PropertyValue $file $property).toString())
    }
    $list.GetEnumerator() | Sort-Object Value
}
```

This gets the output that I am looking for with one small defect. I want to be able to get the key of the hashtable, and use it as a file (type `DirectoryInfo`).

This is a problem that is related to hashtables in powershell in general (as far as I can tell at least, and not specific to the code that I have above (it is included because it is how I came across the need for this, it is not to long, and comments on how to make it "more idiomatic" would be appreciated).

How can I get the file out of the hashtable?

Answer (score 0):

Well, for one you're using `$file.ToString()` as the key, so the defect doesn't so much lie with PowerShell than with your code.

You should be able to use the `DirectoryInfo` instance directly as key in your hashtable (at least it's immutable and overrides `object.Equals`).

Comment: Is there a way that I can do the reverse? (take an entry from the table and then use it as a file) Would it make sense to convert it to a list of some sort first (how would I do that)

Comment: I'm not even sure I understand what exactly you do there.

Comment: Delete files that are longer than 5 min long (if they were mp4 files property 27) and the like